# Editing The ContentControl in Word from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I want to edit the plain text content control in my Word application.

I searched but it seems The "plain text content control" in my target Word document does not respond to

```
objDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Name").Item(1).Range.Text
```

I tried with "ActiveDocument" options but I want it not to work with the active ones.

Code in VBA Excel:

```vb
Sub dataToWord()

    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Excell to Word - Copy\WordTesting1.docx")
   
    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Name").Item(1).Range.Text = "I want to type some text here"
  
    objDoc.Save
    objDoc.Close

End Sub
```

I get:

> Run-time error '445':
> Object doesn't support this action

It refers to the line

```
objDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Name").Item(1).Range.Text = "I want to type some text here"
```

Comment: "i can't execute my code in VBA properly" doesn't describe your problem. Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71276048/edit) link below your question and add details.

Comment: I have edited my link Sir @TimothyRylatt. I only wish to edit the plain text content control or the rich text content control of the target word document as directed with my file path..

Comment: Your question still does not explain what problem you are trying to solve. Saying that the content control does not respond doesn't tell me anything. Do you get an error? If so, what is the error description and which line of your code causes it? Have you checked that the document has a content control with a tag of "Name"? Is the path and filename correct? Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sir @TimothyRylatt thankyou for being patient with me . i have the correct file path .. and i have already set up the "rich text content control" with name and tag of value = "Name" in my word application . And i have further elaborated my question.. thankyou so much for having your time..

Comment: The code in your question is correct so the issue must be with the document.

Comment: Sir @TimothyRylatt.. what could be the issue of the word document.. do you have possible solutions for this?I have also notice the word document is opened as wps by the excel vba command not as word itself..

Comment: That is something you will need to investigate. I cannot help you further.

Comment: Thank you @TimothyRylatt , for giving me a clue .. i have disabled the WPS app and it worked fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled the WPS app . and it worked fine.. it seems it is in conflict with the microsoft word application..